# Is there a way to bypass AWS Lambda package size limit?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda, chromium

I'm pretty sure this question have been asked before multiple times, however, the solutions are normally about using npm, which afaik isn't applicable to Python scripts. So the problem is I hit the package size limit when trying to upload a package that contains Chromium binary, which by itself exceeds the limit, let alone other libraries and the code itself. If I understood correctly,  Lambda layers won't help either as a singular file's size is already more than the allowed limit. Is there a workaround to such issue?

Note: the package contains Selenium library, ChromeDriver and an unpacked Linux Chromium version

Comment: Use lambda container. it gives you 10GB of space for your package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [docker container as Lambda images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html). This will allow you use up to 10GB.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue you did when trying to create a Chromium layer. I found out that you can load a zip file that exceeds the size limit into a layer if you use S3 as the source, so I used that method which did work. By all means use Docker if you are familiar with it but after struggling with the initial issue I chose the easier S3 option.
Edit: removed reference to console since most here should be comfortable using the CLI.

Comment: Quite frankly, I tried this option, too, but turned out there is a limit as well, so I guess I'll have to go the Docker path